# PHP Application Server With Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, server

This is my first time developing with PHP. I have been googling around but still, not got the answer.

On my Centos 7 server, I have installed LAMP.

I want to know what the **web server** is and what the **application server** is.

As I know, the web server is **Apache HTTP Server**.

What about **application server**?

From wiki, it said **PHP-FPM**

[List of application servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_application_servers#PHP)

From Stackoverflow, they said Quercus, Zend Server and appserver.io

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225021/do-we-have-any-php-application-servers-not-web-servers)

Comment: Welcome. You only need a web server for Laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation (In fact, you wouldn't even need a web server, since you can use PHP's built-in using `php artisan serve`)

Comment: oh, what about the application server?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand that Apache is the Web Application Server.

> LAMP is an archetypal model of web service stacks, named as an acronym
>   of the names of its original four open-source components: the
>   GNU/Linux operating system, the Apache HTTP Server, the MySQL
>   relational database management system (RDBMS), and the PHP programming
>   language. The LAMP components are largely interchangeable and not
>   limited to the original selection. As a solution stack, LAMP is
>   suitable for building dynamic web sites and web applications.

[Wiki on LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle))

There are different types of application servers like file servers, email servers and web servers. So you don't need an additional server as an application server. Apache is your Web Application Server, also called Web Server.